# Corona SDK - change direction of gravity for single object with accelerometer

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-engine, game-physics

I am building a game in which I want the gravity to tilt according to accelerometer for a single object. How do I do that? I know of gravityScale, but that only changes gravity intensity, and not its direction.

What I have so far is the standard accelerometer gravity code and object declaration:

```
local body = display.newImageRect( "object.png", 70, 70 )
physics.addBody(body)
local function urTiltFunc( event )
    physics.setGravity( 10 * event.xGravity, -10 * event.yGravity )
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", urTiltFunc )]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. But for a more responsible control you should change

```
physics.setGravity( 10 * event.xGravity, -10 * event.yGravity )
```

for

```
body:setLinearVelocity( 10 * event.xGravity, -10 * event.yGravity )
```

Comment: but what I wanted is to have gravity in different directions for different objects (e.g. having horizontal gravity for an object and vertical gravity for the other)